# When did Donquixote Doflamingo eat his String-String Fruit?

Tags: one-piece

I would like to know how long Doflamingo has had his devil fruit powers.

Comment: You can easily find your answer on google. One Piece's wikia page is particularly useful: http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/One_Piece_Wiki

Answer (score 3):

He got his devil fruit from Trebol when he was 10 after he had awakened his  haoshoku haki and knocked out the people who were trying to torture him. This was also shown in the manga, chapter 782

Wiki qute :

> When Doflamingo was ten years old, he awakened his Haoshoku Haki,
>   knocking out a mob set out to torture him. Four young people — Vergo,
>   Trebol, Diamante, and Pica — who would be the future elite officers of
>   Doflamingo's crew, became awed by the rise of one who they deemed
>   worthy to be their new king. Trebol offered Doflamingo power to be
>   their king and to kill everyone who offended him, which took the form
>   of the Ito Ito no Mi and an obsidian black pistol with luxurious gold
>   plating (an ordinary pistol in the anime)

http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Ito_Ito_no_Mi

Comment: Post a picture of the manga chapter inside a spoiler tag and the answer will be a lot better :) or a one piece wikia reference

Comment: There you go :)